# Permutations with ordering and restrictions

Tags: postgresql, combinations, permutation

I have some symbols and I need to arrange them and determine the number of ways in which they can be arranged:

```
(x11,x12,x13); (x21,x22,x23); (y11,y12,y13); (y21, y22, y23); (y31,y32,y33); (z11, z12, z13)
```

Note that while calculating the permutations, the order within the round brackets must be maintained. For instance, one possible order could be `x11, x21, x12, x22, x13, x23` ... Note that here `x13` occurs after `x12` which occurs after `x11`.

How do we determine the total number of permutations with this restriction?

Comment: Please **[EDIT]** your question and add the `create table` statements for the table(s) in question

Comment: The problem presented above is a sql problem that is phrased as a solvable math statement. While it might seem that this is only relevant to people with math background, I suppose people working on databases should have encountered this problem at some point in time.

Comment: If you want to solve it with SQL, you have to provide the table definitions. If you want a "math" solution, remove the `postgresql` tag (I also fail to see what this has to do with distributed transactions)

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to create 2 tables and do a cartesian join:

```
 create table letters (letter  char(1));
 create table numbers (num numeric);

 insert into letters values ('A');
 insert into letters values ('B');
 insert into letters values ('C');

 insert into numbers values (1);
 insert into numbers values (2);
 insert into numbers values (3);

 select letter, num
 from letters, numbers;
```

With more code, you can do this without the "hard tables" and instead hardcode the data within an array, then have postgres use it the same as a table-- just depends on how much data we're talking about.

Then again, I could be completely misunderstanding the problem you're trying to solve as the number of permutations in my example is "number of rows in letters table" times "Number of rows in numbers table"